# How to search through a vecor with a second vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I currently have a vector in a textfile I am reading from. Currently I can search through this textfile fine and get the vector band from each artist (list of bands an artist has played for, reason it is a vector is because each artist has a different number of bands played for). After finding a bands members I would like to re-search exclusively from the list of bands these artist have played for. For example, if I searched `"Nirvanna"` `"Dave Grohl"` would come up. As he also played for the foo fighter I then want to search foo fighters without going back to the start of the code

This is the error received.

> error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type `std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>` (or there is no acceptable conversion)

```
using namespace std; 
string forname; 
string surname; 
vector <string> band; 
vector <string> newband; 
string input;

if (find(band.begin(), band.end(), input) != band.end())
{
    cout << forname << " " << surname << endl;
    cout << "Played for: ";
    ostream_iterator<string> output_iterator(cout, " ");
    copy(band.begin(), band.end(), output_iterator);
    cout << " " << endl;
    cout << " " << endl;
    newband = band;
}

if (find(band.begin(), band.end(), newband) != band.end())
{
    cout << forname << " " << surname << endl;
    cout << "Played for: ";
    ostream_iterator<string> output_iterator(cout, " ");
    copy(band.begin(), band.end(), output_iterator);
    cout << " " << endl;
    cout << " " << endl;
}
```

I want to search through the original vector with this newly declared vector.

Comment: Can you show us the declarations for these objects?

Comment: How does the error relate to the code? I can't see a `==` anywhere. Where is the error referring to? You say you have a vector in a textfile, but the code doesn't seem to have anything to do with text files. What are you expecting the `find` line does? You seem to discard the return value, so why assign `band` to `newband` inside the if statement? Can you show us what is working, followed by what is not?

Comment: @HeathRaftery the `==` is from the failure to instantiate `std::find` from the call `find(band.begin(), band.end(), newband)`

Comment: Do you think that the *two element sequence* `{ "Nirvanna", "Foo Fighters" }` is the same as either the *single element* `"Nirvana"` or the *single element* `"Foo Fighters"`?

Comment: @HeathRaftery This is just a small section of the code where I have encountered a problem. The code is working fine until the second if statement. I have made newband as I want to search this vector again this time with another vector called new band. The error does not relate to a specific line in the code but rather the xutility.

Comment: @Caleth Not entirely sure what you mean they are both strings inside a vector if that helps.

Comment: I'm hinting as to *why* you have an error. You haven't provided a definition for "is *this band name* equal to *that list of band names*", nor should you. You should instead decide what you want to compare

Comment: You might want "is this band name *an element of* that list of band names" for example

Comment: Have a look at [`std::set_intersection`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection), n.b. it requires sorted inputs

Comment: @Caleth I done this for the first if statement but now I want to redo this search with the information gathered from this and it is impossible to predetermine what it will be that's why I need to be able to search a vector with another.

Comment: Ooooh, I had a totally different picture in my head. You might get more useful responses if you re-phrase entirely. For each band, you generate a vector of band members. You then search each of these vectors for a member. If you get a match, you then what to search all the bands for *all* the members of the matching band. Then yes, heed Caleth's advice - `find` looks for an element in a vector, so unless you can use `set_intersection`, need to loop for each element. Eg. `for(auto element : newband) { if (find(band.begin(), band.end(), element) != band.end()) ... `